# A map where the value is a list of lists - how to sort the list?

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map where the Key is a String and the Value is a List of 'Plan' objects.
For each key, I want the value (i.e. the list of Plan objects) to be sorted on the Plan's fee field.

For example,
IF: Plan1 has a fee of 100.20, Plan 2 has a fee of 400.10, Plan 3 has a fee of 10.00
AND: Before sorting the entry is: ["abc", [Plan1 , Plan2, Plan3]]
THEN: After sorting the entry should be: ["abc", [Plan3 , Plan1, Plan2]]

I have tried

```
map.values()
.forEach(lst -> lst.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Plan::getFee)))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

but this did not change the order of the lists.

Is there a way to do this using Streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey here is the solution to your problem, I have also tested on my machine.

If you have a getter method `getFee()` for the fee variable in your Plan Class. Then the below one works well for you.

```
hmap.entrySet().forEach(e->e.getValue().sort(Comparator.comparing(Plan::getFee)));
```

Thanks to @tgdavies for much simpler approach. Here is the code for same.

```
hmap.values().forEach(li->li.sort(Comparator.comparing(Plan::getFee)));
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `values()` instead of `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is sometimes safe, modify existing state within a stream construct is not a good idea.  In this case, I would just go with the standard imperative solution using a for loop.  Streams are not always the best solution.

Here is a demo.

**Some data and declarations**

```
record Plan(double getFee /*other fields as needed */) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%.2f".formatted(getFee);
    }
}

List<Plan> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Plan(100.20),
        new Plan(400.10),
        new Plan(10.00)));
List<Plan> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Plan(90.20),
        new Plan(30.10),
        new Plan(100.00)));

Map<String, List<Plan>> map = Map.of("abc",list1,"def",list2);
```

**Iteration, sort, and output**

- now just iterate the values which are lists.
- then sort each list using the appropriate comparator.

```
for (List<Plan> list : map.values()) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Plan::getFee));
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**prints**

```
abc=[10.00, 100.20, 400.10]
def=[30.10, 90.20, 100.00]
```